# How to properly import connection pool of mysql from a different file in a nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

**EDITED**

After some googling, I changed content of `getPosts` into:

```
try {
    const con = await pool.getConnection()
    const [rows, fields] = await con.execute('select * from posts')
    res.status(200).json(rows)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
    console.log(err);
  }
```

and my `config.js` into:

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise"
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

export default pool;
```

*Though, It has been solved, I am still wondering why do I still need to **reimport** the `dotenv` since I already imported it on top of my `index.js`? that calls my Router*

I hope someone can give an insight/opinion on my query. I watched several tutorials but they only import the **dotenv** once, and it is located on the `server.js` or `index.js`.

**Below is my initial query**

I have a configuration that aims to call mysql pool from a different file in my nodejs controller. If I put the configuration in my controller function, it works fine however if I put it on a separate file then it breaks.

This is what I made so far in my **config.js** :

```
import mysql from "mysql2"

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

export default pool.promise();
```

and on my controller, I am calling the pool like this one:

```
import pool from "../database/config.js";

const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const [rows, fields] = await pool.query("select * from posts");
    //res.status(200).json(rows);
    console.log(rows);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

When run, I am getting this error: `"message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"`
and on the log, the result is:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at PromisePool.query (/project/home/Ammar90/workspace/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:356:22)
    at getPosts (file:///project/home/Ammar90/workspace/server/controllers/postController.js:6:39
...
at Function.handle (/project/home/Ammar90/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -111,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}
```

It works fine if I am doing like this:

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pool = mysql.createPool({
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    });
    
    const promisePool = pool.promise();
    
    const [rows, fields] = await promisePool.query("select * from posts");
    console.log(rows);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```